# Soundcloud:How to have multiple tracks in one player

Tags: api, widget, soundcloud

I'm trying to figure out how to have multiple tracks queued under one player as is the case here [Soudcloud Widget API Playground](https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html), I've tried viewing the source of the page in the iframe but I get an xml error. In short I would like to replicate the player on the soundcloud api playground page without having to authenticate users and retrieve sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to authorise the users, but you have to use playlists in order to show more than one track with SoundCloud widget. You can also show widget for users’ favorites or just particular users’ tracks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks, that clarifies things.